# function to compare the signals of two audio files

Tags: python, audio

Good evening. If possible, I am looking for a function regardless of the language but mainly in python to compare two audio files by their signals to return if they are identical or different. How to do

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
ASsking for resource recommendations is off-topic: we expect you to do that research before posting here.

Comment: Hi Jean Baptiste, your question is quit general, you should edit it with more details and the research you've already done. I assume this is digital signal, are they strictly identical  from the beginning to the end?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this library: https://pypi.org/project/audiodiff/ . If it doesn't work, try searching it here on Stack.

Comment: thank you. I'll take a look. By the way the objective is to compare a voice input to an audio file database to see if what the person said is there or if there is similarity.